# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview

I am getting this error on a row command in my gridview. Here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = University.GetConnectionString();
        con.Open();

        string query = "select [CourseCode], [CourseNumber], [CourseName], [CRN], [Level], [Credit] from CourseTable where Term='" + MyGlobals.currentTerm + " " + MyGlobals.currentYear + "'";

        SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

        DataTable tab = new DataTable();

        adap.Fill(tab);

        gCourses.DataSource = tab;
        gCourses.DataBind();
    }

}



protected void gCourses_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // *** Retreive the DataGridRow
    int row = -1;
    int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument as string, out row);

    GridViewRow gdrow = gCourses.Rows[row];
    DataRow dr = ((DataTable)this.gCourses.DataSource).Rows[gdrow.DataItemIndex];
    string crn = dr["CRN"].ToString();
}
```

.

```
DataRow dr = ((DataTable)this.gCourses.DataSource).Rows[gdrow.DataItemIndex];
```

line throws the exception.

What is wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Care to tell us which line throws the exception?

Comment: Which line is the error?

Comment: DataRow dr = ((DataTable)this.gCourses.DataSource).Rows[gdrow.DataItemIndex]; throws. Edited the question

Comment: Check if this.gCourses.DataSource != null

Comment: yes it is null but i have done the same thing before and worked before what should i do

Comment: Remove if (!Ispostback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the

```
if (!isPostback)
```

from your page load